# Get date time from conversation index timestamp

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-object-model

In Outlook there is a concept of conversation indexes. The original email will have a conversation index like so:

`01017C2A2FF4481FED6C146C98A04E2FDB77CEFE8E239603ED7DE0`

According to many google searches a reply appends a datetime stamp to it
`01017C2A2FF4481FED6C146C98A04E2FDB77CEFE8E239603ED7DE0800000ABF0`

`800000ABF0`

However none of them tell you how to parse this value.

How would you get a DateTime object from that?

Comment: Could it be a hex value in some format? Looking at the link where you got the index from; `06413958E01` is another DateTime. Perhaps anyone can see a link there?

Comment: In case anyone is curious the thread is here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/92108fcd-0993-48ec-860d-35c419856d39/how-can-i-determine-a-new-replyforward-messages-parent-mailitem-in-an-outlook-2010-cnet-addin?forum=outlookdev&prof=required

Comment: Could it be an encrypted value perhaps?

Comment: Not sure, the documentation doesn't say anything about it. Ken Slovak has said in many threads that it's a datetime stamp, but fails to reveal what format it's in or how you might convert it to something readable. All that I've picked up from reading is that it's an 8-byte time stamp, which makes no sense as it's a 10 char string so that would mean it would be at least 10bytes.

Comment: Do you know in what dll the outlook-code is? Perhaps this shows some clues as to how the index gets generated.

Comment: 800000ABF0 doesn't appear to be a Unix timestamp (if it is, it's in the 193rd century), a Javascript timestamp (it's in the year 1987), or a .NET DateTime (it would be January 1st of the year 1 AD). At 10 hex digits, it's a 5-byte value, so not enough to be a `double` value for an Excel date.

Comment: So apparently it's in file time format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx but from what I'm reading file time is a 64bit integer, so let's just say I'm optimistic and I parse `800000ABF0` as a long and then convert that to a date time. I end up with 1/1/1601 7:16:51 am

Answer (score 2):

As you already figured out, the format is specified at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx.

Note however that you cannot cast [FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765906.aspx) structure to date time. FileTime is the number of ticks (1 tick = 100 nanoseconds) since 1/1/1601. 
One of the DateTime constructors takes ticks (8 byte integer) as a parameter.

Comment: +1, but as you say, FILETIME is ticks since 1 Jan 1601, whereas [that DateTime constructor expects ticks since 1 Jan  0001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx), so instead use the static method [DateTime.FromFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime(v=vs.110).aspx).